# Что происходит при обращении двух пользователей на одну view (django) одновременно

Tags: python, django, асинхронность

Я не так давно знаком с Django и Python. Наткнулся на статью https://tproger.ru/translations/django-orm-tips/ и в совете по ограничению времени выполнения запроса указано что Django обычно использует синхронные рабочие процессы.
Не совсем понимаю данную формулировку. Получается если развернуть приложение на продакшене, то если 10 пользователей обратятся на одну и ту же view по конкретному url - то django их обработает по порядку и условно 10-й пользователь будет ждать обработки остальных 9-ти?
Как тогда на Django написаны такие сервисы как google поиск и instagram, если там миллионы пользователей, которые теоретически обращаются на один и тот же адрес.

Буду очень благодарен ссылочкам на эту тему, или просто в каком направлении читать и изучать. Сейчас смотрю про   WSGI и ASGI. В нужном направлении копаю?

Comment: да, они будут обработаны в порядке живой очереди. Но никто не мешает запустить на нескольких ядрах/серверах и скрипт будет отрабатывать в "паралель". Но Если есть обращение к базе или другому разделяемому ресурсы, могут быть нюансы.

Comment: Думаю: держат несколько серверов на нескольких машинах, т.к. возможности обработки ограничены. Причем, с разделением по странам. Базы данных могут быть продублированы, но возникнет проблема синхронизации. Тот же nginx был сделан, чтобы решить проблему одновременного подключения 10к, т.е. он может одновременно обрабатывать 10к запросов, но для большего количества нужно несколько серверов, а чтобы нагрузка на сервера была равномерной, используют балансировщики нагрузки

Comment: Во-первых, можно поставить несколько машин с Django на каждой, как отметили выше. Во-вторых, можно запустить несколько копий Django на одной машине - такие серверы как uwsgi и gunicorn позволяют прописать число воркеров и потоков в настройках